# Simple SQL problem, disambiguating common attributes

Tags: sql

I have a database with a table `Person`, with attributes `ID`, `Name` and `Age`.  I also have a table `WorksFor`, with attributes `ID1` and `ID2`, where `ID1` *works for* `ID2`

I want to list the names of all people who work for somebody at least 2 years younger than them.  How do I do this?

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as such. Also, `WorksFor` does not make it clear if `ID1` works for `ID2` or vice-versa.

Comment: Is the age expressed in units of seconds, days or years?

Comment: Sorry.  Not homework, working through problems posted on the internet, prepping for an upcoming course.  Nobody has started the school-year yet, hopefully :)  Age is in years.  Either one works, but let's say ID1 works for ID2.

Comment: @water.  Don't forget this on the 'Net so accessed by people for all round the world.  Some of the people who access this site are 3/4 of the way through the school year by this time.  What country are you in that has not yet start the school year?  When does your year start?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming ID1 *WorksFor* ID2...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CubeRat.ID,
   CubeRat.Name,
   CubeRat.Age
FROM
   WorksFor W
   INNER JOIN PERSON Boss ON W.ID2 = Boss.ID
   INNER JOIN PERSON CubeRat ON W.ID1 = CubeRat.ID
WHERE
   CubeRat.Age >= (Boss.Age + 2)
```

Comment: "at least 2 years younger" -- I think your predicate needs to be greater than or less than. Also, assuming the same person can work for more than one person, I think you need `SELECT DISTINCT` (or use semijoins).

Comment: Typo: I meant to say "greater than or equal to". Consider a boss who is exactly two years younger: the predicate "at least 2 years younger" would be true. However, your SQL code does not select such a boss.

Comment: "if I assumed that one person could have more than one boss..." -- You assumed one person could have only one boss, this wasn't specified by the OP at all. The OP didn't use the word 'boss', merely stated the rule is "works for". I myself work for more than one person.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that id1 and id2 are fields in one table where id1 - manager's id, id2 - worker id

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM Person p
WHERE p.age > ((PRIOR p.age) - 2)
START WITH p.id2 = *sombody's id*
CONNECT BY p.id1 = PRIOR p.id2
```

*Oracle notation*

Comment: -1. This answer relies on "SQL" that is only valid in Oracle databases, but there is no reason to believe that the OP is *using* an Oracle db (in fact, going on the comments, I'd say it's rather unlikely). It also makes no use of the required `WorksFor` association table.